# How to extend & list all TypeScript class properties and methods in constructor without turning them into properties?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have the following definition:

```
interface ToConstructor<T> {
  new <C extends Partial<T>>(cfg?: C & Partial<T> & ThisType<T & C>): T & C
}
```

The result of `& Partial<T>` is in code suggestion, everything shows with property icon instead of method. like the following image:

[image: All Properties (not wanted)]

What I wanted is the ability to have code suggestion in this way:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need `C & Partial<T>` exactly given that `C` is already constrained to `Partial<T>`?

Comment: Ah - I see it is mostly for giving completions in your object literal argument. I've filed [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16136) for you.

Comment: Cool. thanks. Like you have had pointed out, I'm having a bit hard time bringing type intellisense to a legacy project. I'll subscribe to the bug thread.